# Shouldn't this be using an index instead of where?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT  `member`.`id` ,  `member`.`name` 
FROM  `member` 
WHERE  `member`.`last_active` >  '1289348406'
```

Shows the following output despite `last_active` having an index on it.... shouldn't it say `index` instead of `where` ?

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  member  range   last_active last_active 4   NULL    2   100.00  Using where
```

Answer (score 1):

`Using index` means the query does not touch the table at all:

> `Using index`
>
> The column information is retrieved from the table using only information in the index tree without having to do an additional seek to read the actual row. This strategy can be used when the query uses only columns that are part of a single index.

Since not all fields are covered by your index, it's impossible.

The index itself is of course being used (since the access type is `range`), but it still needs to do the row lookup in the table to retrieve the values of `name` and `id`.

Create a covering index on `(last_active, name, id)` if you want to see `Using index`.

Comment: I only use this query on 1 page, but it's a very active page.  Is it a bad idea to do that for such a simple query?

Comment: To index those fields, since it will only effect this query.  Is it a bad idea to create an index on such a query?

Comment: @Webnet: The `name` seems to be a `VARCHAR` so it can make the index larger, however, it this query is really important, then it needs the cache more than the other queries, so this is a good idea. How large is your table?